# OrderBy with Dynamic Linq and one to many relationship in EF

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, dynamic-linq

I'd like to implement a module for filtering and paging. I understand that to suceed I had to use Dynamic Linq or Reflection, so I started trying to make it work .. but since the field that contains the text to be filtered in a one to many relationship EF not like it.

This code work fine .. but is static :

```
List<Domain.Entities.Action> actions = db.Actions.Include("Menus").Include("ActionDetails")
                                                 .Where(x => x.ActionDetails.Any(y => y.Language.Culture == _currentCulture))
                                                 .OrderBy(y => y.ActionDetails.Select(z => z.Title).Max()).Skip((pager.Index - 1) * pager.Take).Take(pager.Take)
                                                 .ToList();
```

I want the

> .Select(z => z.Title)

Dynamic..

Can someone help me .. I Try a lot of thing .. but no sucess

Ju.

Comment: I think that EF.. support his method overload .. and nothing else .. because it always said that is not support my extension (overload) of the function Select .. with string parameter.. (I construct my own lambda expresion in the function..) I think I must to use SQL.. is not my favorite solution..

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this you need to pass in a parameter of `Funt<Action, TResultType>` `searchCriteria`

Not sure what your method signature is like but this would work if you plan on returning a `List<string>`

```
public List<string> PerformSearch(Func<Action, string> selectCriteria)
{

  return db.Actions.Include("Menus").Include("ActionDetails")
      .Where(x => x.ActionDetails.Any(y => y.Language.Culture == _currentCulture))
      .OrderBy(y => y.ActionDetails.Select(**selectCriteria**).Max())
      .Skip((pager.Index - 1) * pager.Take).Take(pager.Take)
      .ToList();
}
```